# How to update Heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

How do I update my Heroku, my Windows terminal shows the following:

```
»   Warning: heroku update available from 7.47.7 to 7.52.0.
```

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli
Uninstall Heroku CLI and reinstall. It's also just a warning and an update is not required.

Answer (score 43):

You have to run

```
heroku update
```

in the terminal to update the CLI.

If that doesn't work, this means you have the CLI app as an npm or an apt package, in that case you have to run
apt installation:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade heroku
```

npm:

```
npm upgrade -g heroku
```

yarn:

```
yarn global upgrade heroku
```

Refer to the article [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#staying-up-to-date) for more information.

Comment: For Windows Powershell, `heroku update` works.